# How to display selected category in url?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have one product with 2 categories (e.g. apples/pineapples).

If I go to a product in the "Apples" category, "/product/apples/" appears in the URL.
If I go to a product in the "Pineapples" category, "/product/apples/" appears in the URL.

**How can I display the correct category in the url?**

Product in the category "Apples" with url "/product/apples/".
The same product in the "Pineapples" category with the url "/product/pineapples/".

Answer (score 0):

Actually (I think that) **you can't** do that! Because every product has its **only one** page with **only one** link (or Slug) !

Like, If a product can have "**n**" links (1 link for each category is related to), there will be "**n**" extra pages for this product (each one with its proper link).

Hope you understand what I meant above.

If you have any other question, I'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

As Nova mentioned, by default WordPress associates one category for a post (ie. product, blog, etc.) as the primary category, and utilised in the URL.

A possible implementation to resolve your challenge would be to simply create two products (one per category). However, this could come unstuck if you're needing to utilise stock limits.